# One-to-Many Relationship Seeding in Code First

Tags: entity-framework

I have got the following simple model which is being implemented in Code First approach. Department and Courses have one to many relationship. A department can have many courses while a course can belong to exactly one department. Here is the model.

```
public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; } 
       }

 public class Course
{
    public int CourseId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; } 
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
```

}

My problem is I want to Seed them. I want at least 5 values in my Seed function. Here is the Seed function.

```
public class DataInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<StudentRecordContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(StudentRecordContext context)
{
    var departments = new  List<Department>
     {
        new Department {  DepartmentId = 1, Title = "English", Description ="English     Department",  Courses = new List<Course>() },
        new Department {  DepartmentId= 2,Title = "Chemistry",   Description ="chemistry department", Courses = new List<Course>() },
        new Department {  DepartmentId= 3,Title = "Mahematics", Description ="mathematics department", Courses = new List<Course>() },
        new Department {  DepartmentId= 4,Title = "Philosophy",  Description ="philosophy department", Courses = new List<Course>() },
        new Department {  DepartmentId= 5,Title = "Biology",     Description ="biology department", Courses = new List<Course>() }
    };                                                           
    departments.ForEach( t => context.Departments.Add(t));
    context.SaveChanges();


    var courses = new List<Course>
    {
        new Course { CourseId = 1055, Title = "Classic English",  Description = "Some        Description", DepartmentId = 1 },
        new Course { CourseId = 2055, Title = "Applied Chemistry",  Description = "Some Description", DepartmentId = 2 },
        new Course { CourseId = 2056, Title = "Applied Mathematics", Description = "Some Description", DepartmentId = 3 },
        new Course { CourseId = 3041, Title = "MetaPhysics",  Description = "Some Description", DepartmentId = 4 },
        new Course { CourseId = 3024, Title = "Molecular Biology", Description = "Some Description", DepartmentId = 5 },
    };
    courses.ForEach(t => context.Courses.Add(t));
    context.SaveChanges();
```

but this does not work. I am new to EF and Code First... and deadlines ahead... Can anyone help me please as whats the correct way of Seeding the DB.

Comment: http://ehsanghanbari.com/Post/6/getting-started-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 3):

Don't set primary keys in the `Seed()` method. Entity Framework will know that properties with Id in the name will be primary keys.

Try the following in your `Seed()` method:

```
protected override void Seed(StudentRecordContext context)
{
    var departments = new  List<Department>
    {
        // this will have DepartmentId = 1
        new Department { Title = "English", Description ="English Department",  Courses = new List<Course>() },
        // more departments
    };
    departments.ForEach(d => context.Departments.Add(d));
    context.SaveChanges();

    var courses = new List<Course>
    {
        // this will have CourseId = 1
        new Course { Title = "Classic English",  Description = "Some Description", Department = departments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId == 1) },
        // this will have CourseId = 2
        new Course { Title = "Drama",  Description = "Some Description", Department = departments.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DepartmentId == 1) },
        // both of the above courses will be added to Department with DepartmentId = 1
        // more courses
    };
    courses.ForEach(c => context.Courses.Add(c));
    context.SaveChanges();

    // now add the two courses to the department
    departments[0].Courses.Add(courses[0]); // in list departments at index 0 add course from list courses at index 0
    departments[0].Courses.Add(courses[1]); // in list departments at index 0 add course from list courses at index 1
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use the code above? Did it resolve your issue?

Comment: I was having the same issue and this work like a charm for me.

Comment: your answer helped me but please see my answer below for a simpler solution

Answer (score 0):

Since you are generating the primary keys yourself,
you need to put
`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.None)]` 
attribute for CourseId and DepartmentId so that Entity framework will know that you're generating the keys.

A better option would be to keep relying on the EntityFramework for the primary keys, but to change slightly your method

```
   var courses = new List<Course>
        {
            new Course {Title = "Classic English",  Description = "Some        Description", Department=
     new Department {   Title = "English", Description ="English    
Department",  Courses = new List<Course>() }},
           .....
        };
        courses.ForEach(t => context.Courses.Add(t));
```

In that cause you and need to save the courses and since you are associating the Department, it will be saved implicitly.

Good luck with your deadline!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it, you just need to initialize the 'children' before the 'parent', no SaveChanges() needed :

```
var choices = new List<Choices>
{
    new Choices { Description = "Choice1" },
    new Choices { Description = "Choice2" },
    new Choices { Description = "Choice3" },
    new Choices { Description = "Choice4" }
};

choices.ForEach(c => context.Choices.AddOrUpdate(c));

context.Questions.AddOrUpdate(
    p => p.ID,
    new Question { QuestionText = "Question ?", Choices = choices }
    );
```