# Database design using code-first approach in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am designing a database for tests (say `@school`) and I am not sure how to go about the seeding the database (I am using the code-first approach and the models are as below)

My models are as follows:

```
Levels -> Subjects -> Chapters -> Questions -> Options
```

If I have to seed, I would need to create a level and a list of subjects, which in turn would need list of chapters which in turn would need list of questions and then list of options.

This is the code of the models:

```
//Level 
public class Level
{
    public Level()
    {
        Subjects = new List<Subject>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //Navigate
    public virtual ICollection<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
}

//Subject
public class Subject
{
    public Subject()
    {
        Chapters = new List<Chapter>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int LevelId { get; set; }

    //Navigate
    public virtual Level Level { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; }
}

// Chapter
public class Chapter
{
    public Chapter()
    {
        Questions = new List<Question>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int SubjectId { get; set; }
    public int LevelId { get; set; }

    //Navigate
    public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual Level Level { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I'm not sure if you're asking "how to seed" or asking "how to get around issues with dependencies while seeding"...

Comment: its the later actually.

Comment: See possible duplicate (with no accepted answer, but it appears to have an acceptable one...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15628110/one-to-many-relationship-seeding-in-code-first   Also, you can simply create things in the reverse order (i.e. add four options, then add a question that refers to the four options, then add a chapter that refers to the question, etc. However, I believe if you simply create new objects and update their relations in a batch, then finally call `SaveChanges()`, should work...